# Visual Studio, Connected Service, RestApi client generator, Nswag does not manage range definition of status code (4XX)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openapi, openapi-generator, nswag

I have a OpenApi definition like this :

```yaml
'200':
     [...]
'4XX':
     $ref: '#/components/responses/error'
```

Generate C# code by Nswag in Visual Studio 2022 :

```cs
if (status_ == 4XX)
{
```

This code does not compile.

I already try to :

- update the version of Nswag
- Use NswagStudio

Sample of expected code (given by https://editor.swagger.io/)

```cs
if (((int)status_ ) >= 400)
```

Does anyone already fixed that ? And how ?

Thanks you very much